# sort a column based on description

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using below update query to sort the decription columns of my table

```
update t
  set t.weight=tt.new_weight
  from SERVICE_OPTION as t
  INNER JOIN
  (select id, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by COUNTRY_ID order by COUNTRY_ID, SERVICE_OPTION_TYPE_ID, description) as new_weight 
  from SERVICE_OPTION ) as TT
  ON t.id = tt.id;
```

[Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pyPp.png)

[Column Data Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Xs7.png)

Problem : For example in the image attached Between values "1st Year Maintenance" and "10th Year Maintenance" in the description column , it should sort "1st Year Maintenance" as first column , but it is not happeining

Comment: `I am using below update query` ... no you're not, at least not on MySQL, which doesn't have a `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You could create column `maintenance_year` with integer values in the `SERVICE_OPTION` table and sort rows by one. If you need to show common description use concatenation of `maintenance_year` and a predefined string.